# EasyUI datagrid sends an unwanted request

Tags: events, datagrid, jquery-easyui, onbeforeload

I have a datagrid (table) that when created, it sends two requests:

1. the first is an unwanted (not send by me)  it has no parameters (only *rows* and *pagination* when pagination settings is active), it does go the the intended URL.
2. the second is what I programmed (it works fine, with the parameters I send).

**So the question is, what fires that  request ?**

- Note 1: I even add `onBeforeLoad:function(){return false;}` and still sends the unwanted request.
- Note 2: The requests headers are the same, except for the Content-Length.  (of course).
- Note 3: Related question here: http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=560.0 (I already check it)
- Note 4: The version is: v1.10.4

---

### **Here is the code:**

**HTML**

```
<table
    id="data-grid" 
    class="easyui-datagrid"
    style="width:690px; height:660px"
    url=""
    title=""
    rownumbers="false"
    pagination="false"  
    singleSelect="true"
    pageList="[10,20,30,1000]"
    pageSize="1000"
    >
    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#data-grid').datagrid({
    //Lets add the parameters
    queryParams: {
        status_a:   a),
        status_b:   b,
    },
    url: '/path/path',
    columns:[[.....]],

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Remove `class="easyui-datagrid"` from the HTML inside the `<table></table>` definition.

> When a  element has 'class="easyui-datagrid"' attribute, it
>   will be auto created as datagrid component. You don't need to create
>   it again with javascript code. To prevent from making duplicate
>   request to server, don't create datagrid more than once. If you wish
>   to create datagrid in javascript, the simplest way is to remove
>   'class="easyui-datagrid"' from the  element.

More information here: [jeasy topic](http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=560.0)